# Direct User to Extension Options Page on Install

Tags: configuration

I've got a plugin that's a package with 4-5 sub-packages. When the package completes installation, I would like to direct the user automatically to my options page to configure the plugin. I've hunted around, and I don't see how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `postflight` method in your install script for this, like so:

```
class Com_MyComponentInstallerScript
{
    protected $extension = 'com_mycomponent';

    public function postflight($type, $parent)
    {
        JFactory::getApplication()->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_config&view=component&component=' . $this->extension));
    }
}
```

Comment: The one thing that's required is that for this to work, you must specify false as the second argument to the JRoute::_() call. Otherwise the ampersands are encoded, breaking the redirect.